# System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI : The URI is Empty

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am using a URL that works when I put it in chrome, but in my VS C# code the same url when used in (public async static task)

```
using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))  {    
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);    ----------> Error
```

....

```
Method threw exception: 
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The URI is empty.
Result StackTrace:  
at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)
   at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString)
```

I am sure the URL isn't malformed, so I can't figure out what could be the reason for this error . Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please add the url in your question

Comment: Make sure you include the protocol with the url (http or https) - without it the Uri creation will fail.

Comment: its like http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Employees?$filter=minute(BirthDate) eq 40

Comment: @slugster Please see the edit. I am using the http client. Thanks.

Comment: @Novak007 while debugging, do you see that `url` variable contains what you expect? I suspect it has empty string in it.

Comment: @AlexBuyny I am placing the url in app.config and am then using it in a class in the same project using configurationmanager.appsettings["url"]. the url is a key in the app.config file. I guess there must be some error there.

Comment: @AlexBuyny i just put the keys in app config and i can access it, right ? That's what I saw on some other code .

Comment: @Novak007 are you actually debugging your code? You should, so you don't mislead people. I think posting your actual code may help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You posted in the comments that your URL looks like `services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/…`. You are missing the protocol from the URL and the Uri constructor requires it. Try changing it to this:

```
var url = "http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Employees?$filter=minute%28BirthDate%29";
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
```

Note the `http://` - that is the protocol. You might also have to remove the arguments from the URL, but you can quickly test for that.

Comment: actually i used it but still i am getting the error.

Comment: i placed my url in app.config by creating a key value pair and am then accessing it in a class using configuration manager.appsettings . i guess this is a fine way to access it, but empty url means i can't so could you please give a hint as to what might have been wrong

Comment: I fixed this bug today, because I have not add the key/value to AppSetting.